# What does the octothorpe mean in this piece of Javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I am learning Javascript and I came across this piece of code:

```
"...{{#if products.length}}
        <ul class="cart__items" style="max-height:{{height}}px">
            {{#products}}
            <li class="cart-item cart-item--{{id}}">
            ..."
```

What does the '#' symbol before the if statement mean? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If is some templating language. It has nothing to do with JavaScript/HTML. Plenty of templating languages use that type of syntax to denote a method or helper.

Comment: That is a hash symbol, at least that is its commonly used name.

Comment: See e.g. https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/builtin-helpers.html for what it *might* be.

Comment: @luk2302 It has many names: octothorpe, number sign, sharp sign, pound sign.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a piece of Handlebars.js or some other similar templating language code.
If i understand this correctly, in this particular piece of code the octothorpe/sharp sign/etc. just calls an `if` operator to check if `products.length` returns anything above 0 (not `false` / `true` basically) and if `products.length` returns true then that templating language will render the block of code below.